# Nested generics in a swift function

Tags: swift, generics, swift3, swift-protocols

Assume I have this bit of code:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
}

struct MyStruct: MyProtocol {
}

class MyClass<P: MyProtocol> {
    // Required for compiling
    required init() {
    }
}

class MySpecialClass: MyClass<MyStruct> {
}

func foo<P: MyProtocol, C: MyClass<P>>(protocolType: P.Type) -> C {
    return C()
}
```

This compiles and calling

```
let specialClass: MySpecialClass = foo(protocolType: MyStruct.self)
```

creates an instance of type `MySpecialClass`.

What I would like is to not have to pass in the type of `P` so that I could simply call

```
let specialClass: MySpecialClass = foo()
```

and P would be automatically deduced.

Is there any way to make this happen?

Comment: That's too abstract to wrap my head around. Can you give us an example of what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: I have high expectations that @Hamish will descend from the heavens and bless with some next-level explanations on this

Comment: We're using MVVM, which I hate but so be it. I have a bunch of similar views that subclass from a generic type of view, where the generic parameter is a protocol for the view-model associated with the view. So in my example `MyProtocol` => `DisplayProtocol`, `MyStruct` => `MyDisplay`, `MyClass` => `MyView<D: DisplayProtocol>`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, in Swift 3, the type checker just doesn't try too hard to walk through the dependancies between the generic placeholders to assert whether they're considered "used" in the function signature. However, in Swift 4, it will do so (due to [this PR](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/8454), I believe). So you can just define as `func foo<P, C : MyClass<P>>() -> C { ... }` in Swift 4 :) Until then, ColGraff's very sneaky workaround looks like the best you'll get.

Comment: @Alexander Well I don't know quite about that :P

Comment: @Hamish Annnnnd there it is! :D

Comment: @Alexander what does `class MySpecialClass: MyClass<MyStruct>{ }` `MySpecialClass` is a subclass of `MyClass`. OK. But what does `<MyStruct>` mean here? From my objc days, I know it's used to say this class conforms to `MyStruct`...but `MyStruct` isn't a protocol so I'm confused...

Comment: @Honey `MyClass` is a generic type over any type `P` that conforms to `MyProtocol`. `MyClass<MyStruct>` is a type for which `P` is set to `MyProtocol`. `MySpecialClass` is a subclass of this specific type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Hamish already mentioned,

```
func foo<P, C: MyClass<P>>() -> C {
    return C()
}

let specialClass: MySpecialClass = foo()
```

works in Swift 4. The Swift 3 compiler however complains that

```
error: generic parameter 'P' is not used in function signature
```

and a possible workaround is to add a dummy parameter of type
`P?` with a default value:

```
func foo<P, C: MyClass<P>>(dummy: P? = nil) -> C {
    return C()
}

let specialClass: MySpecialClass = foo()
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this will work:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
}

struct MyStruct: MyProtocol {
}

class MyClass<P: MyProtocol> {
  // added a typealias for P
  typealias ContainedProtocol = P
  // Required for compiling
  required init() {
  }
}

class MySpecialClass: MyClass<MyStruct> {
}

// added a default value for protocolType
func foo<P, C: MyClass<P>>(protocolType: P.Type = C.ContainedProtocol.self) -> C {
  return C()
}

let specialClass: MySpecialClass = foo()
```

By adding a typealias for `P` in `MyClass<P: MyProtocol>` we can refer to that type. We then set it as a default value in `foo<P, C: MyClass<P>>(protocolType:) -> C`. The compiler can then deduce `P` from that information.

Martin R’s version seems to work about as well as mine so go with whichever you like best. His seems a bit cleaner as it doesn’t need a `typealias` and it is fairly succinct.

Here’s [his](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44663344/887210) (it was a comment, it’s now an answer):

```
func foo<P, C: MyClass<P>>(dummy: P? = nil) -> C { ... }
```